# Bushed 3" V-belt pulley with unkeyed 3/4" shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, pulleys

Shortly I will have two 3/4" unkeyed shafts needing 3" type-A V-belt pulleys, one each.  They'll each have their own motor driving them, and will need to run to 5000 RPM and possibly higher in the future.  Is anyone making pulleys for keyless bushings?  Or will vibration be reasonable using H-type bushings with compatible pulleys while ignoring the keyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are four shaft connection methods.

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [PTI International](https://www.ptintl.com/four-shaft-attachment-methods/).*

I've used something like the Adaptor style successfully. The ones I used had a slot cut on the shaft clamp. The inner and outer ring are conical fit and as you tighten them up they pull together progressively squeezing on the shaft. They're a nice job.